# Triangle circumcircle

Tags: geometry

Q. A line drawn from vertex A of an equilateral triangle ABC meets BC at point D and the circumcircle at point P.?
Prove that 1/PD = 1/PB + 1/PC.

∆ACD ≈ ∆BPD, ∆CDP ≈ ∆ADB implying 
I. PD/PB = CD/CA and II. PD/PC = BD/AB. 
We have 
1 - PD/PC = 1 - BD/AB (by II.) = (AB-BD)/AB = (BC-BD)/AB (since the triangle ∆ABC is equilateral) 
= CD/CA (since the triangle ∆ABC is equilateral) = PD/PB (by I.) 
Thus we have 1 - PD/PC = PD/PB. Dividing both sides by PD we get 
1/PD - 1/PC = 1/PB. Moving 1/PC to the right side we get the desired equality.

My doubt: can we prove something like PA=PB+PC ?

Answer (score 2):

$PA=PB+PC$ immediately follows from Ptolemy's theorem. Since $PBAC$ is cyclic, we have
$$PA\cdot BC=PB\cdot CA+PC\cdot AB$$
and cancel $BC=CA=AB$ to get
$$PA=PB+PC$$